# В чём разница: Class a & Class<?> a?

Tags: java, generics

Скажите пожалуйста, чем отличаются два случая:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c1 = String.class;      // Строка 3
        Class<?> c2 = String.class;   // Строка 4
        System.out.println(c1 +", " + c2);
    }
}
```

В 3-ей и 4-ой строках мы делаем что-то похожее, но компилятор предупреждает, что `c1` будет ссылкой на объект сырого типа, а `c2` для компилятора -- прекрасная ссылка на прекрасный объект `Class<?>`

Не понимаю разницы. И сырой тип и параметризованный знаком вопроса одинаково заполнены классом `Object` во время выполнения. Да и во время компиляции тот и другой обрабатываются по равному...

Возможно это просто философское предупреждение от Java, что сырой тип он сбивает с пути истины, а `Class<?>` сразу показывает, что программист нацелен пихать в `c2` всевозможные классы?

Comment: Во втором случае вы явно указываете компилятору, что не знаете какой конкретно будет тип.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Брюс Эккель в "Философия Java" пишет, что использование `Class<?>` вместо `Class` предпочтительнее, хотя оба варианта эквивалентны за тем лишь исключением, что при компиляции кода, где используется `Class`, будет выдаваться предупреждение. Кроме этого Эккель отмечает, что использование `Class<?>` указывает, что разработчик более осмысленно подошёл к выбору типа, а не используете просто `Class` по незнанию.

Comment: Есть номер страницы? Хочу воочию так сказать увидеть, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я всю главу "Generics" пролистал, не нашёл такой информации у него...

Comment: Я смотрел англоязычный вариант "Thinking in Java", 4-е издание. Глава "Type Information", раздел "The Class object / Generic class references", страница 402. Вот цитата: "In Java SE5, Class<?> is preferred over plain Class, even though they are equivalent and the plain Class, as you saw, doesn’t produce a compiler warning. The benefit of Class<?> is that it indicates that you aren’t just using a non-specific class reference by accident, or out of ignorance."

Comment: Нашёл! Вот так и учи что-нибудь. Ни черта в голове не остаётся! Разве что догадку, которую вы оправдали, мой разум сформировал так сказать по остаточным воспоминания)
Спасибо большое за ответ!